# Regex conditition

Tags: php, regex, template-engine, preg-replace-callback

I have a problem with my condition on my template class.
What am i doing wrong?

```
/@if\((?P<condition>.*)\)\n*\s*(?P<content>(?s:[\=\"\;\,\$\{\}\_\(\)\.\!\'\-\:\s\/\<\>\w\näöüÄÖÜèéà@]*))@endif/m
```

**REGEX Link :**
https://regex101.com/r/hE4hX3/3

Comment: As I see, it's matched as `'0' == '0'`. What's wrong?

Comment: thats an example :-)
It's about the 2 conditions . It takes them only as one. But i want to accept as two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using list of allowed characters, use the list of forbidden characters with negated character classes. Example:

```
~
@if \( (?P<condition> [^)]* ) \)
\s*
(?P<content> [^@]*+ (?: @(?!endif\b) [^@]* )*+ )
@endif
~x
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/eY2uK2/1)

In place of `.*` for the condition (that doesn't know where to stop), use `[^)]*` that grabs all until the closing parenthesis.

Same thing for the content, use `[^@]*` and check after each `"@"` if `"endif"` follows. *(in this way `"@"` is allowed in the content.)*

Other things: writing `\n*\s*` doesn't make sense because the two are optional and `\s` already contains `\n`, that's why I removed it.

Comment: Thank you too.
Now i have two solutions. The next Challenge are to make implement else in my condition :-D

Comment: isn't all this dances about `@endif` mean exactly `([\s\S]*?)@endif`?

Comment: @vp_arth: not really, it's slightly faster to write it like this, because you avoid the use of a non-greedy quantifier (that is slow by nature) and reduce the number of steps. In addition, note that all quantifiers are possessive to forbid backtracking. This is particularly useful with large text when the backtracking limit may be reached. Keep in mind that when you use a non-greedy quantifier, for each character taken, the following subpattern is tested and must fail to take the next character and so on. The greedy quantifier doesn't have to make this job.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ungreedy operator `*?` and `g` flag to multiple matches to achieve what you want:

`/@if\((?P<condition>.*)\)\n*\s*(?P<content>(?s:[\=\"\;\,\$\{\}\_\(\)\.\!\'\-\:\s\/\<\>\w\näöüÄÖÜèéà@]*?))@endif/mg`

Or simplified:

`/@if\((?P<condition>.*?)\)\s*(?P<content>([\s\S]*?))@endif/mg`

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hE4hX3/5)

---

Regexps is bad tool to make things like this.
For example, you can not to use nested `if`s right now.
Much better is to implement simple parser, which will make its work correct and can be extended to new syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
It works wonderfull :-D.
I learn something on

Comment: Hmm, your answere are a littlebit diferent from the other. But Both
 works great. Now i will analyse both for learn.

Comment: Read under line section of my answer. Regexps are wrong tool for this.

Comment: Do you have an example of a parser?

Comment: First google [result](https://github.com/tomasbonco/comper-template-parser) as an example.